# Is there a way to distinguish whether the state is being triggered directly or through a child?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to find a way to know whether the user is navigating to a parent state directly or the state is being activated because a child is being activated.

Let's say I have these states:

```
var main = {
   name: 'main',
   url: '/main',
   component: 'main'
}

var child = {
   name: 'main.child',
   url: '/child',
   component: 'child'
}
```

I have a function in main component's controller that I only want to run when the user has navigated www.mysite.com!#/main and not run it if the user clicked on a url www.mysite.com!#/main/child

Is it possible to achieve?

I am using AngularJS and the latest version on router-ui.

Comment: _with your unanswered questions I start to think that you need to re-work your logic_

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I wish I could but I don't know how. Doing my best

Comment: you can't rely on navigation (in terms of clicking), user can always just type URL manually and redirect from anywhere. You should consider shoving most of your login into the config, since it is used for routing. You can do a trick with **role**-based access, by using `data: {authorisedRoles: [USER_ROLES.participant]}` logic in your states. Then your service and angular.run can check if you have access depending on user's role (gathered from cookie/session). [More about it.](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty simple and obvious solution that works by checking `$state.current.name`. Don't know why I haven't though of it earlier.

My solution is something along these lines

```
ctrl.$onInit = function(){
   if($state.current.name === 'main'){
       // do something
   } 
   else if ($state.current.name === 'main.child'){
       // do something else
   }
   else {
       // do completely something else
   }
}
```

Maybe this helps somebody in the future.